# Why would the gas cost be so high on a simple contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, evm

The contract does not run, it cannot get enough gas.

Here is the txn -

```
> > eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x069fdab662d9bb69f0af6a526c60289cb3d2cfa4cba1345fdd53e517cef136aa")
> {   blockHash:
> "0x1b5d679bb6ea82bf8f4ab54bdb8adf30d7b7d30a1158cc8ff9c71868bf675120", 
> blockNumber: 4904,   contractAddress: null,   cumulativeGasUsed:
> 4712388,   from: "0x0c12901e1ec7f80763cd433e8eca0c837d11a0c1",  
> gasUsed: 4712388,   logs: [],   logsBloom:
> "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
> root:
> "0xc7e148d032b30b43c13cf3b219f17f6f405ab10e21e65bdca0c3cabfa60afeca", 
> to: "0x82ab361a9ca7359d7719f2f1aa6f1a95604c3ffd",   transactionHash:
> "0x069fdab662d9bb69f0af6a526c60289cb3d2cfa4cba1345fdd53e517cef136aa", 
> transactionIndex: 0 }
```

> 

The gas used us 4712388 which is my gaslimit-1. The contract is simple so we have an issue with genesis I guess. I have two nodes in total and I attached them via addPeer.

> ~/blockchain$ cat genesis.json  {   "config": {
>       "chainId": 33,
>       "homesteadBlock": 0,
>       "eip155Block": 0,
>       "eip158Block": 0   },   "nonce": "0x0000000000000033",   "timestamp": "0x0",   "parentHash":
>   "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
>   "gasLimit": "0x47e7c5",   "difficulty": "0x100",   "mixhash":
>   "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
>   "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",   "alloc":
>   {} }

Contract -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract RegisterContract {

    uint public contractWeight;
    mapping(bytes32=>string) public contracts;

    function addContract ( string jsonInput, bytes32 hashKey) public {

        contracts[hashKey] = jsonInput;

    }

    function addWeight (uint weight) public {
        contractWeight = weight;

    }

}
```

Comment: I found out it is the string that is causing the problem.

Comment: Create an answer for your own question, explaining clearly the problem and mark it as the correct answer. This is both allowed and encouraged when you solve your own problem.